# Expo Error when Running AWS App on web browser only (AmplifyI18n)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, react-native

My aws-react-native app runs perfectly on Android  (using expo), but when I try to use the "w" option in expo and then run it in the browser, I get the following error page. It looks to me some lib is missing or something like that, does anyone knows what I could try to make it available on the web?

Tested on Android and it has worked fine - the problem seems to happen just in the browser and it seems to be aws-amplify related.

My App.js imports:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';   
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


// Necessary for "Auth" service
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';
import { Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import awsconf from './source/aws-exports';
Auth.configure(awsconf);
Analytics.configure(awsconf);

//Necessary for Translation
console.log(Localization.locale);
import { I18n } from 'aws-amplify';
import dict from  './source/translations';
I18n.setLanguage(Localization.locale);
I18n.putVocabularies(dict);

...
```

Error Page:

```
×
ReferenceError: dict is not defined
Module.../../../../../../../../../../../environment/node_modules/aws- 
amplify-react-native/dist/AmplifyI18n.js
node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/AmplifyI18n.js:14
  11 |  * and limitations under the License.
  12 |  */
  13 | 
> 14 | export default dict = {
  15 |     'fr': {
  16 |         'Loading...': "S'il vous plaît, attendez",
  17 |         'Sign In': "Se connecter",
View compiled
__webpack_require__
/home/ubuntu/environment/webpack/bootstrap:724
  721 | };
  722 | 
  723 | // Execute the module function
> 724 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, 
 hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  725 | 
  726 | // Flag the module as loaded
  727 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
/home/ubuntu/environment/webpack/bootstrap:101
   98 |         );
   99 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  100 |     }
> 101 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  102 | };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are things you need to install and set up.

1. Ensure you’re using the latest version of `babel-preset-expo`
2. Install `react-native-web`, and `react-dom`.
3. Add the property **“web”** to the expo.platforms array in your
   `app.json`

```js
    "expo": {
        "platforms": ["web"]
      }
```

4. Then run `expo start` with the latest version of the `expo-cli`
   after the bundler has started, you can press the **w key** to open
   your app in the browser.

NOTE: Because most libraries in the `React-native` community do not support the **Web**, it may not work as well as **RNW** can expect.

Comment: Hi, I have checked all those points, all seems to be fine, and even though the app still does not run on web, with the errors above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `dict =` from your `export default dict =`, so that it looks like:

```
export default {
  'fr': {
    ...
```

Comment: @FZs The presentation could be better, but this *is* the right answer. OP's existing code attempts to assign to a nonexistent variable and then export the expression result of that assignment. Simply default-exporting the expression instead and letting the importing module name the imported variable *is* the right way to do this.

Comment: Thanks folks... however this looks like standard code from Aws Amplify:  Module.../../../../../../../../../../../environment/node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/AmplifyI18n.js
node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native/dist/AmplifyI18n.js:14
  11 |  * and limitations under the License.
  12 |  */
  13 | 
> 14 | export default dict = {
  15 |     'fr': {
  16 |         'Loading...': "S'il vous plaît, attendez",
  17 |         'Sign In': "Se connecter",